# Error Number 1054 on CRUD application

Tags: php, codeigniter, model, error-handling

i am getting this error anyone know what is could be the cause of this ? i think its something with the model but cant figure out.

> Error Number: 1054
>
> Unknown column 'id' in 'order clause'
>
> `SELECT * FROM (`tblquestions`) ORDER BY` id `asc LIMIT 5`
>
> Filename: C:\wamp\www\Surva\system\database\DB_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 330

**MODEL**

```
private $primary_key = 'QID';
private $table_name = 'tblquestions';

function get_paged_list($limit=10, $offset=0, $order_column='', $order_type='asc')
{
    if (empty($order_column) || empty($order_type)) {
        $this->db->order_by($this->primary_key, 'asc'); 
    }
    else {
        $this->db->order_by($order_column, $order_type);
        return $this->db->get($this->table_name, $limit, $offset);
    }
}

function count_all()
{
    return $this->db->count_all($this->table_name); 
}

function get_by_id($id)
{
    $this->db->where($this->primary_key, $id);
    return $this->db->get($this->table_name);
}

function save($question)
{
    $this->db->insert($this->table_name, $question);
    return $this->db->insert_id();  
}

function update($id,$question)
{
    $this->db->where($this->primary_key, $id);  
    $this->db->update($this->table_name, $question);
}

function delete($id)
{
    $this->db->where($this->primary_key, $id);
    $this->db->delete($this->table_name);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please Change id to qid as:

```
      SELECT * FROM (tblquestions) ORDER BY qid asc LIMIT 5
```

you have given wrong column name in query.

Comment: @user2143150 do you mean that the qid is in capital i.e QID right! , well it doesn't matter in the database, database only differs in users value i.e our data not it's table structure

Comment: so it dose not matter if the letters are uppercase or lowercase ?

Comment: yes for it's structure(i.e table column name etc.) , it does matters for user entered values i.e for data that user enter in the table it is case sensitive

Comment: i am not getting this at all

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26230/discussion-between-sandip-and-user2143150)

Comment: see the demo http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a15da/3/0  I have given column name type in small letters in where clause still it works

Comment: i had the id set as id in the controller instead of QID fixed that works now tnx for ur help

Answer (score 0):

Include all the columns you want to select when using `order by, having, group by` clauses..
SAY -- `SELECT ID FROM (tblquestions) ORDER BY ID asc LIMIT 5`

Or If you want also do like this `SELECT * FROM (tblquestions) ORDER BY tblquestions.ID asc LIMIT 5`

The ColumnName must be selected specifically before applying `order by, having, group by` clauses..

```
Here you can change this---
$this->db->order_by($this->primary_key,'asc');  to
$this->db->order_by("tblquestions".$this->primary_key,'asc');
```

Comment: i ma new to codeigniter dount really understand what u said can u explain more in how would i go about of doing this ? tnx for answering bdv.

Comment: Just replace your Query by this
`SELECT ID FROM (tblquestions) ORDER BY ID asc LIMIT 5`

I mean replace " * " by Column Names

Comment: do i place this in $this->db->order_by  line ?

Comment: Here you can change this---
    `$this->db->order_by($this->primary_key,'asc');`  to
    `$this->db->order_by("tblquestions".$this->primary_key,'asc');`

Comment: That was an example yaar... What exactly I mean is

The error means that you are trying to `order by` a column name that is used in more than one table. Update your order_by statement with the name of the table that has the column you want to order by. 
<br/>
For example:

`$this->db->order_by('Employee.id');`

Comment: that cant be right because i only have the QID in tblquestions and and it is unique.